# How can I get my very basic script in r to work

Tags: r

I am trying to write my first very basic script in r. Going through various posts and r tutorials is not taking me far. The issue am trying to resolve is as follows:
I have the following hourly data in a file:

```
year mo dy  time  ucomp vcomp temp   Rhum  rain
2020 07 09 00:00   -1.1   0.5   11.8 54.0     0
2020 07 09 01:00   -1.6   0.3   10.1 62.4     0
2020 07 09 02:00   -1.6   0.4    9.2 67.2     0
2020 07 09 03:00   -2.2   0.4    8.2 70.5     0
2020 07 09 04:00   -2.2   0.7    7.5 75.2     0
2020 07 09 05:00   -1.7   0.6    7.1 80.2     0
2020 07 09 06:00   -0.7   1.0   10.0 74.9     0
2020 07 09 07:00   -2.7  -1.2   15.8 61.4     0
2020 07 09 08:00   -5.4  -3.2   19.8 51.4     0
2020 07 09 09:00   -5.6  -3.7   23.3 43.4     0
2020 07 09 10:00   -5.0  -4.1   26.1 36.0     0
2020 07 09 11:00   -4.5  -4.2   28.2 28.1     0
2020 07 09 12:00   -2.9  -3.7   29.1 25.2     0
```

I am trying to read this data and select the line that corresponds to the hour am at, e.g. at 10h I want to copy the line

```
2020 07 09 10:00   -5.0  -4.1   26.1 36.0     0
```

Having copied the line I want to construct the wind speed and direction from the formula

```
windDir <- function(ucomp, vcomp) {
 (180 / pi) * atan(u/v) + ifelse(v>0,180,ifelse(u>0,360,0))
}
```

then write wind direction and speed as E, NE, SE, ... (depending on direction) and the other values all in another file.

Below is how far I have gone in developing my script, which is very little.

```
setwd("/home/zmumba/04_R_Scripts")
library (lubridate)
fileName <- "myhourly.txt"

con <- file(fileName,open="r")
my2day<-sys.date()

while (length(oneLine <- readLines(con, n = 1, warn = FALSE, header="T")) > 0) {
 I believe I have to put my code here, but how?
}
close(con)
```

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

R can certainly be tricky to learn. I see a couple issues right off the bat. For example, assigning a variable within a length call is iffy. I would highly recommend going through *R for Data Science* by Hadley Wickham. That would be the best way to get up to speed.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference, but for me to acquire the book and figure out will take me weeks, which is my problem and nobody else's anyway.